# Trying to end a process that is blocking me from deleting a folder

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, process, files-folders, process-hacker

For the past couple days, I've been trying to end a process (ACORIGINS.exe) that is keeping me from deleting a folder (Ubisoft) that I wish to delete. Every time I try deleting the folder, it says that [multiple files are open in ACORIGINS.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfAv1.png), which makes me believe that ending the process is the only way for me to get rid of the folder. At the time that I am typing this question, I have downloaded Process Hacker, and searched up the folder that I want to delete. The only process that appeared was ACORIGINS.exe, which hasn't even been started up on my computer since a few days ago, because I was downloading or updating it. What I wanted to do here was terminate the process, but instead of letting me do so, it gave me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJQcV.png). I used [tasklist on command prompt, and ACORIGINS.exe appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtAcc.png), so I decided to use taskkill and got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0xHC.png). I have no more ideas to get rid of the process, so I'd appreciate if anybody could help me.

Comment: Its crashed while terminating.  You may have to just restart your PC.

Comment: There are numerous tools to unlock a file and delete it, e.g., LockHunter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tasklist shows process but taskkill is unable to kill it, even as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/1183057/tasklist-shows-process-but-taskkill-is-unable-to-kill-it-even-as-admin)

Comment: Please do not [edit your question to declare “Answered” or “Solved”](https://superuser.com/posts/1760432/revisions) as you have done. If you have an answer, please just post it as an answer below. You are always welcome to do so. This site is a question and answer site; not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic process where name="ACORIGINS.exe" call terminate
```

Check if this code works. I got reference from [Tasklist shows process but taskkill is unable to kill it, even as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/1183057/tasklist-shows-process-but-taskkill-is-unable-to-kill-it-even-as-admin)